# How to keep proxmox VM / CT up and runnig after a cluster node goes down in HA Cluster without VM/CT access loss even one second?

Tags: containers, virtual-machine, high-availability, ceph, proxmox

i've just configured proxmox HA cluster / Ceph(Monitor, Manager, OSD) with 3 nodes.
**After a node goes down, the VM /CT switches perfectly to another node of the cluster**. But the problem is that it takes about 5 minutes to restore the VM / CT status after switching to another node.

So what i'd like to ask is : **What should i configure else TO KEEP VM / CT UP AND RUNNIG AFTER SWITCHING TO** another node of the cluster with the fact that **no access to VM / CT gets lost even one second** ???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

HA in Proxmox is not perfect, I stopped using it because this reason. You can have 3 independent containers and control traffic thru reverse-proxy, firewall or other external source.